# copy value of an automatic variable to another variable in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'd like to do `rule` variable contain the value of `$@` in the attribution line, instead of the reference. Example:

```
rule=$@

all:
    @echo "Running Rule: $(rule)"

rule1: all
    @echo "Do something here"

rule2: all
    @echo "Do another thing here"
```

My expected result would be:

> Running Rule: rule2
>
> Do another thing here

when run `make rule2`. But the result I have is:

> Running Rule: all
>
> Do another thing here

Is it possible to make this attribution?

---

[edit]

In others words, what I need is get parent target name, i.e. the parameter of the `make` command typed by the user in the terminal console.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `$@` is always set to the current target, never to the parent target (why would it do that?)

The best option available to you (given the limited description we have of what you're really trying to do) is to use [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

```
all:
        @echo "Running Rule: $(rule)"

rule1: rule = rule1
rule1: all
        @echo "Do something here"

rule2: rule = rule2
rule2: all
        @echo "Do another thing here"
```